# How to increase space above and below dashed line using arydshln package

Tags: tables, booktabs, arydshln

I'm using the `arydshln` package to insert a dashed line between two lines of data, but when I look at the result of a large table in `\scriptsize` the line appears to be too close to the lower data line.  Here is a sample of my code.  Does anyone know how to increase the space above and below the dashed line?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{arydshln,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \begin{center}
     \caption{Stuff}
      \begin{tabular}{clc|clc|}
         \toprule
Rank&   Method  &   $h=1$&Rank& Method  &   $h=6$ \\
\midrule
1   &   Naive (SS)  &   0.064   &   1   &   Mean (Cr)   &   0.067   \\
2   &   Autobox (MA)    &   0.141   &   2   &   Naive (All Parts)   &   0.076   \\
3   &   SS  &   0.312   &   3   &   DRP (All Parts) &   0.078   \\
4   &   DS  &   0.315   &   4   &   DS  &   0.175   \\
5   &   Mean (DS)   &   0.484   &   5   &   Autobox (DS)    &   0.201   \\
6   &   MA  &   0.563   &   6   &   Mean (DS)   &   0.290   \\
7   &   Autobox (SS)    &   0.578   &   7   &   Naive (Cr)  &   0.316   \\
8   &   Mean (MA)   &   0.593   &   8   &   Autobox (All Parts) &   0.328   \\
9   &   Mean (SS)   &   0.664   &   9   &   Naive (SS)  &   0.433   \\
10  &   DRP (All Parts) &   0.807   &   10  &   Mean (SS)   &   0.462\\
20  &   Cr  &   4.167   &   12  &   Cr  &   0.985   \\
\hdashline
    &       &       &   20  &   SS  &   8.605   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way. Note you shouldn't use vertical rules with booktabs. Also don't use the `center` environment within `table` – it adds unwanted vertical spacing. Use the `\centering` directive instead. I added the `caption` package to have a decent vertical spacing between caption and table wghen the caption is *above* the table.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{arydshln,booktabs, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
     \caption{Stuff}
      \begin{tabular}{clc|clc|}
         \toprule
Rank& Method & $h=1$& Rank & Method & $h=6$ \\
\midrule
1 & Naive (SS) & 0.064 & 1 & Mean (Cr) & 0.067 \\
2 & Autobox (MA) & 0.141 & 2 & Naive (All Parts) & 0.076 \\
3 & SS & 0.312 & 3 & DRP (All Parts) & 0.078 \\
4 & DS & 0.315 & 4 & DS & 0.175 \\
5 & Mean (DS) & 0.484 & 5 & Autobox (DS) & 0.201 \\
6 & MA & 0.563 & 6 & Mean (DS) & 0.290 \\
7 & Autobox (SS) & 0.578 & 7 & Naive (Cr) & 0.316 \\
8 & Mean (MA) & 0.593 & 8 & Autobox (All Parts) & 0.328 \\
9 & Mean (SS) & 0.664 & 9 & Naive (SS) & 0.433 \\
10 & DRP (All Parts) & 0.807 & 10 & Mean (SS) & 0.462\\
20 & Cr & 4.167 & 12 & Cr & 0.985 \\[0.5ex]
\hdashline\noalign{\vskip 0.5ex}
    & & & 20 & SS & 8.605 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]